# No match for call while launching thread on constructor

Tags: c++, multithreading, constructor, stdthread

I have a `class Foo`, that must launch a thread (which is a method `loop()` on my class) on the constructor.

My class is something like this on the header file:

```
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo();
  ~Foo();
private
  void loop();

  std::thread m_thread;

  //more stuff.
}
```

And the source file is:

```
Foo::Foo()
{
   m_thread(&Foo::loop, Foo()); // <---- No match for call '(std::thread) (void (Foo::*)(), Foo)'
   m_thread.join();
}

Foo::~Foo()
{
  m_thread.kill(); // <---- ??? how to do this?
}

void Foo::loop()
{
   while()
   {
       //do stuff.
   }
}
```

**Question:**

**1 -** How can I fix the error on the `Foo constructor`? I'm having the `"no match for call`" error when compiling.

Bonus question:

**2 -** How can I kill the thread on the destructor of the object?

Comment: 1 - make the constructor public

Comment: ... well thats not the problem, but still I guess you wanted to have a public ctr, right?

Comment: Note that you're having your thread call `loop()` on a separate `Foo` object, so you're going to infinitely recurse into more and more `Foo` constructors.  You probably want to pass your `this` pointer to the thread.

Comment: sorry...constructor was public...mistype that here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You're attempting to *call* a thread object, not initialize it here:

```
m_thread(&Foo::loop, Foo());
```

You should set assign it the appropriate value:

```
m_thread = std::thread(&Foo::loop, Foo());
```

But this will default-construct another `Foo` object, which will launch a thread, which will default-construct a `Foo` object, which will launch a thread, which will...

So, maybe you mean to launch the thread on the instance itself, in which case you need

```
m_thread = std::thread(&Foo::loop, this);
```

Note that usually it is preferable to *initialize* data members in the constructor initialization list, but since the thread calls a member of `Foo`, it is best to launch it once the object has been constructed.

2) You can join the thread in the destructor. Just make sure no exceptions propagate out of the destructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can also define your m_thread object in the constructor initializatin list like that :

```
Foo::Foo() : m_thread(&Foo::loop, this), End(false)
{
   m_thread.join();
}
```

A simple way to end your thread is to use a member variable End, set it to true in the constructor and loop on it in your thread

```
Foo::~Foo()
{
    End = true;
    m_thread.join(); // <---- ??? how to do this?
}

void Foo::loop(Foo* This)
{
   while(This->End == false)
   {
      /*Do something*/
   }
}
```